# Django Signal Profile Creation Issue

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I created a user profile section on my application and im trying to implement automatic creation of a profile when a user creates an account on my registration page, but ever since i added the signal and receive functionality, im getting the following error now. If i remove the two definitions in signals the registration form will work correctly again, so something in the signals is causing this to fail.

invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Here is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from users.forms import UserRegisterForm
from django.core.mail import send_mail


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your account {username} has been created, you can now login !')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
        messages.warning(request,(form._errors))
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html')


@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'users/dashboard.html')
```

Signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/

Django Version: 2.2.9
Python Version: 3.7.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'forms.apps.FormsConfig',
 'crispy_forms',
 'users.apps.UsersConfig',
 'points.apps.PointsConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\rzuchowski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\rzuchowski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\rzuchowski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\missinglink\users\views.py" in register
  12.             form.save()

File "C:\Users\rzuchowski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py" in save
  130.             user.save()

File "C:\Users\rzuchowski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py" in save
  66.         super().save(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\rzuchowski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  741.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "C:\Users\rzuchowski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  790.                 update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using,

File "C:\Users\rzuchowski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py" in send
  175.             for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)

File "C:\Users\rzuchowski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py" in <listcomp>
  175.             for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)

File "C:\missinglink\users\signals.py" in create_profile
  10.         Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

File "C:\Users\rzuchowski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\rzuchowski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in create
  422.         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)

File "C:\Users\rzuchowski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  741.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "C:\Users\rzuchowski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  779.                 force_update, using, update_fields,

File "C:\Users\rzuchowski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  870.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "C:\Users\rzuchowski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
  908.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "C:\Users\rzuchowski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\rzuchowski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
  1186.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "C:\Users\rzuchowski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1367.             for sql, params in self.as_sql():

File "C:\Users\rzuchowski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in as_sql
  1311.                 for obj in self.query.objs

File "C:\Users\rzuchowski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in <listcomp>
  1311.                 for obj in self.query.objs

File "C:\Users\rzuchowski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in <listcomp>
  1310.                 [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]

File "C:\Users\rzuchowski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in prepare_value
  1251.             value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)

File "C:\Users\rzuchowski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_db_prep_save
  793.         return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)

File "C:\Users\rzuchowski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_db_prep_value
  788.             value = self.get_prep_value(value)

File "C:\Users\rzuchowski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  1825.         return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /register/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default ='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    grade = models.CharField(max_length = 2, default= "")
    bio = models.TextField(max_length = 255, default= "")
    teacherpsid = models.CharField(default = "", max_length = 50, unique = True)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

Comment: I can add a profile manually from the admin section.

Comment: Can you add `Profile` model code to the question?

Comment: Your second receiver is run for every save (for both creates and updates). So it is also run when a user is created. Guessing that's causing your problem. You can add a "if not created:" check on your second receiver

Comment: Or use a single receiver, doing different operaitions with an if clause on created flag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your receiver is taking the wrong arguments:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(instance, created, **kwargs):  # no sender argument!
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

The instance was passed to the argument `sender` so `instance` was empty.

Note that your second receiver is also running every time, including on creation (add `else` in your first receiver to do what you want). It seems a useless receiver anyway, why would you save the profile if the user is changed? The relationship is maintained anyway.

Comment: Did you override the `save()` method of `Profile` model?

Comment: I got it working, it was an issue on my rule on my models.